# Bandcamp API sales_report endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script

I could really do with some help with one call to the Bandcamp API. For every request I make to /http://bandcamp.com/api/sales/1/sales_report/ the response contains:

*/"error_message":"JSON parse error: 757: unexpected token at ''/*

Here's an example of an unsuccessful call:

```
var artistId = <my band_id>
var memberArtistId=''; // optional - only applies to label accounts
var start_time='2018-01-01 23:59:59';
var end_time='2020-01-01 23:59:59'; // optional
var format='json'; // optional
 
 var objParams = {
  "band_id": artistId,
  "member_band_id": memberArtistId,
  "start_time": start_time, 
  "end_time": end_time,
  "format": format
}
   
var parameters = {
  headers:{Authorization:'Bearer '+access_token},
  method:"post",      
  payload:objParams,
  muteHttpExceptions:true
 };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(token_url,parameters).getContentText();
```

I get the same using the sample at /https://bandcamp.com/developer/sales/. I think that probably I'm not escaping or encapsulating characters correctly in the JSON object making the request.

Maybe someone could provide me with a successful example so that I can see where I'm going wrong? A curl command would be cool but any format would be OK. I happen to be using Google Apps Script (so, basically JavaScript).

Thanks very much!

Comment: I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But unfortunately, I cannot test the script. So when my proposal was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this is a solution for my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that in your situation, the request body might be required to be sent as JSON value. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var parameters = {
  headers:{Authorization:'Bearer '+access_token},
  method:"post",      
  payload:objParams,
  muteHttpExceptions:true
 };
```

#### To:

```
var parameters = {
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token},
  method: "post",
  payload: JSON.stringify(objParams),
  contentType: "application/json",
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `access_token` and `objParams` are correct. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))